# Mac connected to iPhone hotspot but no internet

Tags: iphone, mac, network, wifi, sleep-wake

My MacBook disconnects from my iPhone hotspot automatically after it enters sleep mode. But after it exits sleep mode and reconnects to the hotspot, there is no internet. This can be solved by restarting the mac and connecting it to the hotspot again, but it’s very annoying and I have to restart it multiple times a day. I wonder if there is any solution.

Comment: What kind of hotspot are you using? Does your Mac get an IP address when it reconnects after sleep?

Comment: I am using my iphone’s hotspot. It says “self assigned ip”

Comment: Did you toggle the hotspot on the phone, or restart the phone instead of the Mac?